# Does using QueueClient.OnMessage inside an asynchronous method make sense?

Tags: azure, asynchronous, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I am calling an async method InsertOperation from an async method ConfigureConnectionString. Am I using the client.OnMessage call correctly? I want to process the messages in a queue asynchronously and then store them to the queue storage.

```
private static async void ConfigureConnectionString()
    {
        var connectionString =
           "myconnstring";
        var queueName = "myqueue";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await Task.Run(() => InsertOperation(connectionString, queueName, table));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("ElapsedTime " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes + " minutes.");

    }


 private static async Task InsertOperation(string connectionString, string queueName, CloudTable table)
    {

        var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
        client.OnMessage(message =>
        {

            var bodyJson = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            var myMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerifyVariable>(bodyJson);

            Console.WriteLine();

            var VerifyVariableEntityObject = new VerifyVariableEntity()
            {
                ConsumerId = myMessage.ConsumerId,
                Score = myMessage.Score,
                PartitionKey = myMessage.ConsumerId,
                RowKey = myMessage.Score
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your code, as it stands, is a bit confusing - for example, you don't use the table variable that you pass to InsertOperation. Can you explain the logic you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OnMessageAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_OnMessageAsync_System_Func_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) provides async programming model, it enables us to process a message asynchronously.

```
client.OnMessageAsync(message =>
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessMessage(message));
    //you could perofrm table and queue storage in ProcessMessage method
}, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the actual logic you want to achieve, it looks like you are not using OnMessage correctly.

OnMessage is a way to set up the queue client behavior for a long running client. It makes sense, for example, if you have a singleton instance in your application. In that case, you are specifing to the client how you want to handle any messages that are put in the queue.

In your example, however, you create the client, set up the OnMessage, and don't persist the client, so it effectively doesn't get anything accomplished.